# Getting error ValidateDOMNesting in reactjs how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am getting error in my console:
Below is the code of content.js which displays everything clearly but will the warning give any problem on rendering when my web app becomes complex. 
Screenshot:
[image]

content.js file :

```
class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            matches:[],
            loading:true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('api/matches')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        matches:res,
        loading:false
      })
    })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <div>>Loading...</div>
        }

    return (
      <div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div id="one">
                    <p class="match">Match {this.state.matches[0].id}</p>
                    <p><h4>{this.state.matches[0].team1}</h4></p>
                    <p>VS</p>
                    <p><h4>{this.state.matches[0].team2}</h4></p>                  <====  LINE   39
                    <div class="winner">
                        <h3>Winner</h3>
                        <h4>{this.state.matches[0].winner}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stats">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Stats</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: <p>{this.state.matches[0].team1}</p>

Comment: @stack26 Should I remove `<h4>` so then should I style it later as I want text size to be large.

Comment: yes  exactly !! You have to style is differently giving a separate className

Comment: @stack26 Can you answer it necessary changes so that I can upvote

Comment: Remove the `<p>` arround your `<h4>----`

Comment: Sure , I am doing it

Comment: Since `h4` provide semantic benefits (for SEO) whereas styling the `p` only gives a visual differences, it would be better to use the `h4`

Comment: If the text is not a heading, you should use the `p` tag and give it a className as @stack26 suggest

Comment: But React does not allow that, There are other ways to  optimize seo

Comment: @stack26 what does React not allow? Using `h4` :S

Comment: i am sorry , it allows but will throw warning when h4 is used inside inside p. the same thing happens when you use p as the child of tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this document [document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).Either you remove h4 tag or remove p tag outside it.

```
<p className="your_class">{this.state.matches[0].team1}</p>
```

or you can do it like this

```
<h4>{this.state.matches[0].team1}</h4>
```